# Send command to raspberry pi from hosted website

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, remote-access, thermal-printer

I've hosted a website on my raspberry pi using nginx with this tutorial:
https://andrewmichaelsmith.com/2013/08/raspberry-pi-wi-fi-honeypot/

It's a captive portal, and the website is a quiz. Upon completion of the quiz, I'd like the submit button to print a "prescription" from a thermal receipt printer connected to the raspberry pi which was setup using this tutorial:
https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi?view=all

I can run the command from the tutorial: "lpr location/image_file.png" to print from the raspberry pi's CLI. So the question is, how can I link the submit button to send this command to the RPi?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that was wanting to answer a similar question, I figured it out on my own:

The answer is enabling php forwarding in your nginx server block, (just do a quick search on how that works with FastCGI) and having a php file that sends:

shell_exec("YOUR COMMAND HERE")

:)